# How to split a comma seperated string and insert into html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the string:

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
```

I want this string to be separated and inserted into html.

<s>Each time I refresh the page</s> the numbers should iterate one by one.

Edit: Sorry, ignore the above line. If I have a button clicked it should iterate through the strings and display one by one.

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: *Each time i refresh the page the numbers should iterate one by one* I am confused with this line. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Its hard to understand the objective here! Add an example of how exactly (markup) you want the above to be inserted into your page.

Comment: on what you need to separate string ?

Comment: use cookie or local storage instead...

Comment: If you want a client-side change upon each refresh, you will have to store an index as a cookie or in Local Storage so each new refresh can know which counter value to use next.  Then, when the page loads, you read the saved value, update the saved value and set the new value into the page.

Comment: you need to use a client side storage like a cookie or local storage

Comment: sorry if i have a button clicked it should iterate through the strings and display one by one

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jnktehpq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
var n=numbers.split(','),
    i=0;
$('#button').on('click', function(){
   $('#show').text(n[i++]);
   if(i==n.length) i=0;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="show"></div>
<button id="button">Increment me</button>
```

```js
   var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
   var n = numbers.split(','),
     i = 0;
   $('#button').on('click', function() {
     $('#show').text(n[i++]);
     if(i==n.length) i=0;
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show"></div>
<button id="button">Increment me</button>
```

If you want it on canvas then try it like,

**Jquery**

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
var n=numbers.split(','),
    i=0;
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font="18px Arial";
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    ctx.fillText(n[i++],20,20);    
});
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<button id="button">Increment me</button>
```

Hope, this helps,

```
var indexLetter=0;
function paintletter(retryletter) {
    var chars = charscontainer.innerHTML.split('');

     // comment the blow code
     /*letter = retryletter ||
             chars[parseInt(Math.random() * chars.length,10)]; */
     // add the below code
      letter = retryletter ||
             chars[indexLetter++];
      if(indexLetter==chars.length) indexLetter=0;
      c.width = container.offsetWidth;
      ......
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/v9pm6f8w/2/)

Comment: thanks rohan can this be applicable for html5 canvas too?? i need to load the numbers inside canvas

Comment: Yes you can try and make an online demo if you get any errors.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/karthikchandran/v9pm6f8w/   ..see this i have tried in this but errors..i need the letters to be loaded in oreder ..here they have used math.random to randomly load the strings into the canvas..how to i orderly  do it..can you help me

Comment: See my last updated answer  and demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/v9pm6f8w/2/

Comment: is there any way tat i could place hint points like 1 2 3 over the alphabet for the kids to know how to draw @rohan

Comment: Yes, you can by making an array of numbers variable and show with `ABCD..`. But both variables show have equal length, otherwise after printing `9` you need to reinitialize the array index from `0`.

Comment: i couldn't get @rohan.. can you please help me out by placing 123 over letter A..  http://jsfiddle.net/karthikchandran/fq78jmds/

Comment: is it possible to place over the letter in small size like a hint for where to start the draw @rohan

Answer (score 2):

Refer this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/e1ky6rtj/

On Click of button:

```
<button onclick='clicked()'>ClickMe</button>

function clicked(){
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
var c= numbers.split(','); //Split a string into an array of strings
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    alert(c[i]);
}
```

Comment: i need the strings to be displayed in dom

Comment: @karthik As and when you click on button, it should display one by one in some div?Or All of string at a time?

Comment: @karthik i dont think so..Canvas has altogether different used in 2D graphics. Also, If my answer helped, do accept!.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div id="x"></div>
<button id="y">---</button>
```

js:

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";

$('#y').click(function () {
    numbers.split(",").forEach(function(n, i) {
        console.log(n + ' ' + i);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('<p>').text(n).appendTo('#x');
        }, i * 200);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwht2L4n/)

Comment: this is good but when i click btn all nos are displayed ..i need only the next string to be displayed ..like if it is 1 and if i click the btn i should only display 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the defualt function

ie,

`var array = numbers.split(",");`

array would be a normal javascript array

Answer (score 1):

```js
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
$(numbers.split(',')).each(function(){
    $('#main').append('<div>' + this + '</div><br />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.split(',')](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) this returns array of data which split by `,`

var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
    var spltValue = String(numbers).split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < spltValue.length; i++) {
        var aData = spltValue[i];
        console.log(aData);
    }
});
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq9sx0L2/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
var dataArray = numbers.split(",");
```

push to an array and handle it accordingly.